# XLSX- how to get rid of the default namespace prefix x:?

Tags: namespaces, openxml-sdk, openxml, spreadsheetml

I'm generating XLSX spreadsheet using OOXML SDK, and I need to get rid of `x:` namespace prefix. How can I achieve this?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("template.xlsx", true))
            {
                //Save the shared string table part
                if (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType().Count() > 0)
                {
                    SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart = 
                                       doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType().First();
                    shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save();
                }

                //Save the workbook
                doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

Here, the original XLSX file is coming from Excel 2007 and doesn't have the prefix, however, after the save operation the prefix appears. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of the prefix? What problem is caused by the prefix?

Comment: Because the client has some weird software which fails to import the file with the prefix - and there is nothing to do with that. I just removed the prefixes manually, and it was imported ok.

Comment: How about applying a post-processing step to your XSLX document that removes the prefix and sets the appropriate default namespace? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413050/c-how-to-remove-namespace-information-from-xml-elements/413088#413088

Comment: That's can be good, just I need to 'wash' only a specific namespace, and  leave all others intact. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I actually have the same problem but with Excel 2010. Excel will ignore XmlMaps added to the file if the x: prefix is present. Remove the prefix manually, and it works...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of the stylesheet linked by divo that strips only a single namespace and copies the rest verbatim:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:x="namespace-to-strip" 
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@x:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm much mistaken the original file is namespaced as well - only in the form of a default namespace. What's wrong with the namespace in the first place?

Comment: You're right. That's what I want - the default namespace.
That's because my client has some weird software which fails to import the XLSX with the prefix - and there is nothing to do with that. If I  remove the prefixes manually, it imports ok.