# automatic generation xml(vdx) file base on another xml file

Tags: xml, templates, xls, visio, text-processing

I need some help with generating XML files. I need to generate a new `vdx` file based on an original `vdx` file using some kind of template. New files must differ from orginal file only in one way, such as ID numbers. This distinction should be read from an `xls` file (every `vdx` file should be generated with anothed data). Which tools can help me with this task (is this possible using only XML code)?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to extract the data:

- Save each xsl file as [xlsx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- Parse the unique identifiers from the resulting SpreadsheetML
- Save the extracted data in an XML file
- Transform the XML file to vdx using XSLT

**References**

- [Reading Data from SpreadsheetML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/10/reading-data-from-spreadsheetml.aspx)
- [XLSX- how to get rid of the default namespace prefix x:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199041/xlsx-how-to-get-rid-of-the-default-namespace-prefix-x)
- [From SpreadsheetML Stylesheet](http://www.ewbi.com/ewbi.develop/samples/from.spreadsheetml.xslt.txt)
- [Create and Process SpreadsheetML](http://etutorials.org/XML/xml+hacks/Chapter+3.+Transforming+XML+Documents/Hack+42+Create+and+Process+SpreadsheetML/)
- [Transforming Open XML documents using XSLT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-using-xslt.aspx)