# remove xmlns="something" from xml document using linq to xml

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm parsing an xml file.

the first line of xml looks like;

```
<DataSetMenu xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSetMenu.xsd">
```

I'm using below code to parse the xml.

```
string filename = Request.QueryString["file"].ToString();
XElement xdocument = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("xml\\" + filename));

xdocument.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();

IEnumerable<XElement> MenuGroups = xdocument.Elements();

sb.Append("<link href='StyleSheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
foreach (var xel in MenuGroups)
{

    if (xel.Elements("MenuCatName").Any())
    {
        Int32 MenuCatID = Convert.ToInt32(xel.Element("MenuCatID").Value);
        string MenuCatName = xel.Element("MenuCatName").Value;
        sb.Append("<div class='CategoryDiv'><h1 class='category'>" + MenuCatName + " </h1>");
        GetGroupItems(xdocument, MenuCatID);
    }
}
```

But when ever xml file's first node contains :

```
 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSetMenu.xsd"
```

It doesn't work at all. when i try to access xml's data it gives me error, **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

**XML FILE**

```
    <DataSetMenu xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSetMenu.xsd">
    <MenuCategories>
     <MenuCatID>10108</MenuCatID>
     <MenuCatName>SPEICALS</MenuCatName>
     <BusinessEntityID>20137</BusinessEntityID>
    <DisplayIndex>10107</DisplayIndex>
     <MenuCatDesc />
      <Visible>true</Visible>
      <ImagePath />
   </MenuCategories>
   <MenuCategories>
    <MenuCatID>10109</MenuCatID>
    <MenuCatName>GENERAL MENU</MenuCatName>
    <BusinessEntityID>20137</BusinessEntityID>
     <DisplayIndex>10108</DisplayIndex>
      <   MenuCatDesc />
       <Visible>true</Visible>
       <ImagePath />
    </MenuCategories>
   <MenuGroups>
     <MenuGroupID>110079</MenuGroupID>
    <MenuCatID>10108</MenuCatID>
     <MenuGroupName>SPECIAL OFFERS</MenuGroupName>
     <MenuGroupDesc />
     <Visible>true</Visible>
     <DisplayIndex>0</DisplayIndex>
     <MenuTypeID>1</MenuTypeID>
    <ImagePath />
     <ServiceTimeEnforced>false</ServiceTimeEnforced>
    <ServiceStartTime>1900-01-01T11:00:00-06:00</ServiceStartTime>
     <ServiceEndTime>1900-01-01T15:00:00-06:00</ServiceEndTime>
     <Monday>true</Monday>
    <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
    <Thursday>true</Thursday>
    <Friday>true</Friday>
    <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    <Sunday>true</Sunday>
   </MenuGroups>
   </DataSetMenu>
```

Give me a solution so that it works fine. Or any way to remove this attribute.

Thanks.

***Now It's now working here***

```
 private void GetGroupItems(XElement xdocument, Int32 MenuCatID)
{

    var MenuGroup = from nm in xdocument.Elements("MenuGroups")
                    where (int)nm.Element("MenuCatID") == MenuCatID
                    select nm;

    foreach (XElement  GroupName in  MenuGroup)
    { 
        Int32 MenuGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(GroupName.Element("MenuGroupID").Value);
        string MenuGroupName = GroupName.Element("MenuGroupName").Value; 
        sb.Append("<div class='IType'>" + MenuGroupName + " </div>");
        sb.Append("<table class='restaurantlist'><tbody><tr><td class='righttd'>");
        GetMenuItems(MenuGroupID, xdocument);
        sb.Append("</td></tr></tbody></table>");
        sb.Append("<div class='restaurantlistdiv'><div style='clear: both;'></div>");
    }
}
```

please tell me, how should i modify this?

Comment: its really a big file. showing you first few nodes.

Comment: I have update my question with xml code.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to go to the originator of the XML file and tell them to give you a XML file with a valid namespace....if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify namespace when you're querying your XML.

Create `XNamespace` instance:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/DataSetMenu.xsd");
```

Then use [`XNamespace` + String operator implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_addition.aspx):

```
public static XName operator +(
    XNamespace ns,
    string localName
)
```

within `Elements()` method call, like that:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> MenuGroups = xdocument.Elements();

sb.Append("<link href='StyleSheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
foreach (var xel in MenuGroups)
{

    if (xel.Elements(ns + "MenuCatName").Any())
    {
        Int32 MenuCatID = Convert.ToInt32(xel.Element(ns + "MenuCatID").Value);
        string MenuCatName = xel.Element(ns + "MenuCatName").Value;
        sb.Append("<div class='CategoryDiv'><h1 class='category'>" + MenuCatName + " </h1>");
        GetGroupItems(xdocument, MenuCatID);
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh thanks a lot. Its working. But somewhere i'm getting a problem. Thats also because of namespace. Please tell me how to resolve it. I'm updating my question. thanks.

Comment: i hvae updated my question. Please check the last one code added. I need you little more help to resolve it. thanks.

Comment: right now i have given static namespace in "XNamespace.Get()". But if i want to make it dynamic. Because it may be possible that different xml files contain different namespaces. can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to remember here is that you are not working with an attribute, but the namespace declaration. That's why you can't just remove the attribute. See if the suggestions at [C#: How to remove namespace information from XML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413050/c-how-to-remove-namespace-information-from-xml-elements) help.